# How to disable accentuated char suggestion on long click on mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

When pushing a key for a long time, you expect to print a lot of times the same char. 
Instead of that, I now have a popup suggesting all accentuated chars.

How to disable that and come back to a classic keybaord function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As given in the link by Tom Gewecke, you can disable the `Character Picker` by typing the following in a terminal :

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Answer (score 17):

Open a terminal (e.g. *Terminal.app*) and write

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

then press Enter.

Any open applications will still use the "Press and Hold", but if you quit them and then open them again they should work as expected (use key repeat instead of "Press and Hold").

Reference: http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/07/os-x-107-lion-getting-rid-of-character.html

Comment: Can you please summarize to help future users even if the link breaks?

Comment: Any running applications will need to be quit and reopened for it to take effect in the application.

Answer (score -1):

Pop-over menu also won't appear when the Key Repeat slider is set to Off in the Keyboard pane of System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: But it will also not repeat the character, which is the desired effect of the questioner